# Проблема в raw_input

Tags: python, python-3.x

При запуске пишет name 'raw_input' is not defined

```
a = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
print (a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input()` - версия Python 2.x. В Python 3.x это заменили на обычное `input()`

```
a = input("What is your name?: ")
print(a)
```